# How to convert a tuple of tuple or int to set in python

Tags: python-2.7, set, tuples

I have the following kind of input

```
tuple_of_tuple_or_int = ((3,8),4) # it may be like (4,(3,8)) also
```

I want to convert it to a set like

```
{3,8,4} # in any order
```

I have tried this:

```
[element for tupl in tuple_of_tuple_or_int for element in tupl]
```

But it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that flatten with a conditional but that conditional must result in an iterable so in this we use a 1-tuple:

```
[element for tupl in tuple_of_tuple_or_int 
         for element in (tupl if isinstance(tupl, tuple) else (tupl,))]
```

This cause the input `((3,8),4)` to be processed as if it was `((3,8),(4,))`.

```
Python 2.7.3
>>> tuple_of_tuple_or_int = ((3,8),4)
>>> [element for tupl in tuple_of_tuple_or_int 
...          for element in (tupl if isinstance(tupl, tuple) else (tupl,))]
[3, 8, 4]
```

This could be made more general by replacing `isinstance(tupl, tuple)`.

Comment: This works for me! :D Thanks a lot! +1 for isinstance(tupl, tuple)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit **overkill** for your problem but it may help future users to flat nested `tuples` into a single `tuple` or `list`:

```
def flatten(T):
    if not isinstance(T,tuple): return (T,)
    elif len(T) == 0: return ()
    else: return flatten(T[0]) + flatten(T[1:])

tuple_of_tuple_or_int = ((3,8),4)

print flatten(tuple_of_tuple_or_int) # flatten tuple
# (3, 8, 4)

print list(flatten(tuple_of_tuple_or_int)) # flatten list
# [3, 8, 4]
```